# ACRA device filtering for sending reports

Tags: android, acra

I am developing an application where I have implemented ACRA for log reporting, that's implemented and activated by default in my app configuration. However, when I am developing and entering in a typical trial-error phase, my development device sends a lot of dummy error reporting that are of no interest for me (as I have all information of eclipse).

It gets annoying as I need to discard a significant amount of reports in acralyzer.

What I would like to do, is having a way to configure ACRA that, for a specific device ID, it will not send a report. Some kind of device filtering that allows me developing without filling the database with several reports.

I have been navigating through the documentation of [advanced use of ACRA](https://github.com/ACRA/acra/wiki/AdvancedUsage) and I have not been able to find it. The only options coming to my mind is commenting the call to the constructor of ACRA when developing for later on activate it when doing the app release.

Is there any other option to solve this problem in a more durable way avoiding me to patch temporary files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using something like this as my development report sender:

```
private static class DummyReportsSender implements ReportSender
{
  @Override
  public void send(CrashReportData arg0) throws ReportSenderException
  {
      //Dummy Reporter - nothing send
  }
}
```

and then at the Application#onCreate():

```
if (BuildConfig.DEBUG)
{
  ACRA.getErrorReporter().setReportSender(new DummyReportsSender());
}
```

Comment: Um... what you are showing is the way to send a forced error, but not how to filter the device, isn't it?

Comment: Why do you need to filter the device? Isn't it enough not to send reports if you are in  "DEBUG" mode?

Comment: Sorry I missunderstood your suggestion. What you suggested me is a different solution to my problem.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to do this with ACRA OOTB.

You could override and decorate the DefaultExceptionHandler after calling ACRA and ignore particular Exception instances. But it sounds like overkill to me.

Either use a different Acralyzer instance for dev, or delete/ignore your dev exceptions.

My dev exceptions are always -SNAPSHOT so they are easy to ignore.

Comment: You mean that you are using a fork called -SNAPSHOT in your development environment which is different from the production option you use, is that correct?

Comment: My dev branches are always called <someVersion>-SNAPSHOT. I use Maven to build, so I only have a concrete build version at point of release.

Comment: Arg... I prefer to use stable versions of ACRA as I don't have the skills to play with the prorgamming of ACRA...

Comment: Anyhow, from my point of view the answer has been given: ACRA development did not considered this capability and is not implemented. I will need to use a workaround.

Comment: I think you misunderstood. I use production ACRA OOTB. But I can readily ignore any errors on my crash server generated during development because the versions for my products during development always end in "-SNAPSHOT"

Comment: Yep, I did not understood you properly. Actually what you are telling me is what I am doing with a different naming convention. Just playing with the database I can fix a workaround I would say.